# SublimeText: How to bind 'Home' key to move cursor to a position 0 in the line (not to the first non-space char)?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Sublime will move cursor to the first non space character on the line:

Original cursor position:

```
function test() {
    var a = 42|
}
```

After press Home:

```
function test() {
    |var a = 42
}
```

Desired cursor position after the Home key pressed:

```
function test() {
|    var a = 42
}
```

In notepad++ I fixed this easily by remapping from HOME to DISPLAY_HOME (I might not remember the exact literal name)

Please help (if that is possible at all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hardbol` does the trick:

- Preferences-> Key Bindings - User

  ```
  { "keys": ["home"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "hardbol"} }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Just press "Home" button twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{ "keys": ["home"], "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "bol"} }
```

I found it in a forum. http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5830